Charts data in List cells changes when scrolling
I have a List in which each cell has a chart. The data for the list is generated once and stored in the chartData property. However, there is a bug. When scrolling the list, the charts in the cells change places: if we scroll the list a couple of cells down and then return to the top, then the first cell will have a completely different chart from what was before scrolling. However, only the chart changes, the number Text remains unchanged
struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let data: [Double]

    var isPositiveTrend: Bool {
        return data.last ?? 0 > data.first ?? 0
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let chartData: [ChartData] = (0..<90).map { index in
        ChartData(number: index, data: (0..<12).map { _ in Double.random(in: 1...10) })
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(chartData) { data in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(data.number)")
                    Chart(Array(zip(data.data.indices, data.data)), id: \.0) { idx, val in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("index", idx),
                            y: .value("value", val)
                        )
                        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                        .foregroundStyle(data.isPositiveTrend ? .green : .red)
                    }
                    .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))
                    .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartXAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartLegend(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



I could reproduce this but I used more static data and not only did they change as you say but to me it looks like they are repeating in some way so I clearly didn't have 90 unique charts. I haven't seen any pattern in this and whatever I try to log and add to Text fields looks fine and in the correct order so it seems to be about the charts more than the data.

Random and indices won’t work in the a View struct, the data needs to be loaded into a model first and then write the View to display it with no extra work.

Another option is to replace List{} with ScrollView(.vertical){}

It seems that it is a bug appears from iOS 17.4 (See https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/750052)
According to the discussion above:
Adding .id(VALUE) to Chart(), where VALUE is unique per Chart()
will solve the issue
struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let data: [Double]

    var isPositiveTrend: Bool {
        return data.last ?? 0 > data.first ?? 0
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let chartData: [ChartData] = (0..<90).map { index in
        ChartData(number: index, data: (0..<12).map { _ in Double.random(in: 1...10) })
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(chartData) { data in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(data.number)")
                    Chart(Array(zip(data.data.indices, data.data)), id: \.0) { idx, val in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("index", idx),
                            y: .value("value", val)
                        )
                        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                        .foregroundStyle(data.isPositiveTrend ? .green : .red)
                    }
                    .id(data.id) // <--------  ADD THIS
                    .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))
                    .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartXAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartLegend(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Make sure ChartData conforms to Hashable or provide a stable id for ForEach.
Add an explicit id for the ForEach loop to help SwiftUI properly manage the views.
struct ChartData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let data: [Double]

    var isPositiveTrend: Bool {
        return data.last ?? 0 > data.first ?? 0
    }

    static func == (lhs: ChartData, rhs: ChartData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let chartData: [ChartData] = (0..<90).map { index in
        ChartData(number: index, data: (0..<12).map { _ in Double.random(in: 1...10) })
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(chartData, id: \.self) { data in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(data.number)")
                    Chart(Array(zip(data.data.indices, data.data)), id: \.0) { idx, val in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("index", idx),
                            y: .value("value", val)
                        )
                        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                        .foregroundStyle(data.isPositiveTrend ? .green : .red)
                    }
                    .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))
                    .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartXAxis(.hidden)
                    .chartLegend(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I don't think this solves the problem, conforming to Identifiable should be enough.

Yes, unfortunately this doesn't help

That == that only compares id will likely cause issues
